# angularjs ng-repeat in multiple divs

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have got an array whose elements I populate in a div as follows:

```
<div align="center" ng-show="showWords" class="container">
   <div ng-repeat="word in whichArray" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
      <h4><div class="col" style="padding-left:9cm; padding-right:5cm">{{whichArray[$index]}}</div></h4>
      <h4><div class="col">{{whichArray[$index + 1]}}</div></h4>     
   </div>
</div>
```

This looks like following:

[image]

The jsfiddle I referred to http://jsfiddle.net/vm3j4akp/ has such elements populated in a very clean way (i.e. there is enough space between adjacent elements and all second elements on each row start at the same position)

I am using however Ionic so I will have to use Ionic grid and not the bootstrap grid. **How can I rearrange these divs nicely?**

Answer (score 0):

what does class="col" mean? we have to use some width like col-sm-6 instead only class col. we can remove padding in style also

Comment: It's Ionic grid, so they have different conventions. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even

Comment: No problem! jsfiddle I posted has no extra css, so I wonder why it doesn't work on mine

Comment: what happens if we remove those padding

Comment: I have tried giving paddings at jsfiddle. There also it is breaking. Please make sure we need padding

Comment: No even after removing paddings second elements are misplaced. It looks like it has something to do with <h4> tags, removing it makes the whole thing little better

Answer (score 0):

I managed a work around like this:

```
<div align="center" ng-show="showWords" >
   <div ng-repeat="word in whichArray" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
      <div class="col" align="left" style="margin-left:9cm;">{{whichArray[$index]}}</div>
      <div class="col" align="left">{{whichArray[$index + 1]}}</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```